# Installation screen - rollback barrier

Tags: install4j

Can any other screen group added after the Installation screen be a rollback barrier.
As part of upgrade, a database upgrade needs to be performed post binary installation. If the database upgrade fails the requirement is to rollback the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rollback barrier on the "Installation" screen and select the "Rollback barrier" property on the other screen.

Comment: Observation is that having a rollback barrier on some action in new screens created after the Installation step does not trigger a rollback of the binaries installed during the Installation step.

Comment: You're right, you have to remove the rollback barrier on the "Installation" screen". I've edited my answer.